# How do I filter out data based on a string?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a set of rows in one sheet in a book, and I want to create a new sheet in the book such that it takes all rows from the first sheet, and copies column A in it where column B matches a certain string (in the same row).

pretty sure it is possible, but lost how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible using a
[FILTER function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759).

For example, we take a sheet containing addresses and extract all the
streets whose name contain `rd`. We will use the following FILTER function:

```
=FILTER(B2:B11,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("rd",B2:B11)),"No results")
```

Here is what happens when I click in cell F2, paste my filter in the
formula bar and press Enter (the text in F1 was typed by hand):

[image]

For more information see for example the article
[Excel FILTER Function](https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-functions/excel-filter-function).